# Facial Recognition_1

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'read'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - image is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'image'

I am getting this error from the code and am wondering on how to fix it.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
res, img = cap.read('/Example/photo.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.axis('off')

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

I try to fix the read function but has not worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

cap.read() method doesn't take a filename as an argument. Instead, it reads the frames from the video capture device (camera). So, you need to remove the filename argument and just call cap.read().

You need to check whether cap.read() was successful in reading the frame from the camera. You can do this by checking the value of res. If it's True, then the frame was successfully read, and you can proceed with the rest of the code. If it's False, then you need to handle the error.

Here's the corrected code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
res, img = cap.read()

if not res:
    print("Error reading frame")
else:
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGBA)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

This code should capture a frame from your camera and display it using matplotlib. If you want to read an image file instead of capturing a frame from the camera, you can replace cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) with img = cv2.imread('/Example/photo.jpg') and remove the cap.read() line.

Comment: Thank you for helping with my issue but also turns out to be that the CvtColor is now having the issue.

Comment: If cv2.cvtColor() is causing an issue, it could be because the img array is None or empty. This could happen if cap.read() fails to read a frame from the camera.

You can add some print statements to check if img is None or empty, and if cv2.cvtColor() is returning an error.

This should give you more information about the issue you're facing. If img is None or empty, you may need to check your camera settings or try a different camera. If cv2.cvtColor() is failing, you may need to investigate the specific error message to determine the cause.